# Entering List Values in Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given a list as follows:

```
l = [['43.195', '-22.17', '-43.17', '-22.198', '-43.198', '22.197'], ['43.196', '-22.14', '-43.179', '-22.188', '-43.188', '22.192']]
```

I need to add the values from this list to two separate columns of a dataframe. Example: Values where sublist indices of l are even `(l [0] [0], l [0] [2], l [1] [0], etc.)` go to the `LATITUDE` column; and values that indices of sublists of l are odd `(l [0] [1], l [0] [3], l [1] [1], etc.)`,go to the `LONGITUDE` column. The dataframe already exists, but the `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` columns do not.

I am trying the following, unsuccessfully:

```
d = pd.DataFrame()
i = 0
j = 0
if i < len(l):
   if j < len(l[i]) and j%2==0:
      d['LATITUDE'] = ', '.join(map(str, l[i][j]))
      j += 1
   elif j < len(l[i]) and j%2!=0:
      d['LONGITUDE'] = ', '.join(map(str, l[i][j]))
      j+=1
   i += 1
d
```

Note: Each sublist corresponds to one instance of the Dataframe.

Expected output:

```
         LATITUDE             |     LONGITUDE
'-43.195', '-43.17', -43.198  | '-22.17', '-22.198', '-22.197'
'-43.196', '-43.179', -43.192 | '-22.14', '-22.188', '-22.192'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will using `reshape`

```
pd.concat([pd.Series([x[::2],x[1::2]]).str.join(sep=',') for x in l],1).T
Out[280]: 
                        0                      1
0   43.195,-43.17,-43.198  -22.17,-22.198,22.197
1  43.196,-43.179,-43.188  -22.14,-22.188,22.192
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want output in string format. You may use numpy strides and `map` and `join` to create string of values

```
a = np.array(l)
pd.DataFrame({'LATITUDE': map(', '.join, a[...,::2]), 'LONGTITUDE': map(', '.join, a[...,1::2])})

Out[416]:
                   LATITUDE               LONGTITUDE
0   43.195, -43.17, -43.198  -22.17, -22.198, 22.197
1  43.196, -43.179, -43.188  -22.14, -22.188, 22.192
```

Comment: @Costa.Gustavo:  it's in your sample data of `l`

Answer (score 0):

you can be done using chain function of itertools like below

```py
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd
l = [['43.195', '-22.17', '-43.17', '-22.198', '-43.198', '22.197'], ['43.196', '-22.14', '-43.179', '-22.188', '-43.188', '22.192']]

chained = list(chain(*l))
pd.DataFrame(dict(LATITUDE=chained[::2], LONGITUDE=chained[1::2]))
```

Comment: So it is not separating the even indices from the odd indices of the sublists.

Comment: @Costa.Gustavo ya my bad, you can use chain function for that